# Alineación de items para barra de navegación Bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap, flexbox

Quiero hacer una barra de navegación de dos columnas, lo que hice fue hacer dos navs dentro del mismo div "container" y eso por ahora me funcionó, el segundo nav se alineó tal cual quiero. Pero el primero, el de arriba, se alinean los iconos a la izquierda como quiero, pero el logo no logro llevarlo al centro.

**Imagen1**: Es como deseo que quede

**Imagen2**: El logo se queda en la derecha y no se centra.

Necesito una ayuda con esto por favor. Gracias

[image: Así quiero que quede]

[image: Así es como lo tengo según el código que coloqué]

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#"><img src="/assets/logo.svg" width="200"></a>
                <div class="d-flex">
                <button class="navbar-toggler justify-content-start" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                
                </div>
                
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto barraIcons">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#"><img class="icon1" alt="" width="30" height="24"></a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link " href="#"><img class="icon2" alt="" width="30" height="24"></a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link " href="#"><img class="icon3" alt="" width="30" height="24"></a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
        </nav>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light d-flex">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <div class="navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-evenly">
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">SALE</a>
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">E-SHOP</a>
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">LOOKBOOK</a>
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">CAMPAÑA</a>
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">LOCALES</a>
                </div>
              </div>
         </nav>
      </div>
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Bootstrap estás utilizando?

Comment: Estoy usando Bootstrap 5

Answer (score 1):

Lo solucioné usando la clase `start-50` que es el equivalente a `left:50%` y cambiando la posición a `absolute`, también añadí la clase `px-0` al contenedor para eliminar los bordes y que la barra ocupe todo el ancho de la pantalla, y añadí la clase `navbar-brand` al div que contiene el logo como se recomienda en la documentación oficial de Bootstrap.

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 5 css -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid px-0">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark">
        <div class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center">
            <a class="nav-link position-absolute start-50" href="#"><img src="/assets/logo.svg" width="200"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex">
            <button class="navbar-toggler justify-content-start" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto barraIcons">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#"><img class="icon1" alt="" width="30" height="24"></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link " href="#"><img class="icon2" alt="" width="30" height="24"></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link " href="#"><img class="icon3" alt="" width="30" height="24"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light d-flex">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <div class="navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-evenly">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">SALE</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">E-SHOP</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">LOOKBOOK</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">CAMPAÑA</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">LOCALES</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div><!--//container-fluid-->
```